# R plot title with variable name

Tags: r, plot

I looked through a few other posts and I still can't figure out how to do something much simple.

Suppose:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
a <- 23.54
```

Now I want to plot:

```
plot(x, y, main=c("Interesting Title", a))
```

However, that puts 23.54 on a new line, treating it as a second title. How can I make it in one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Try `main=paste("Interesting Title", a)`